# C# JSON string to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have the following class in C#:

```
public class Caption
{
    public string line;
    public string timestamp;
}
```

I have created some Caption objects and added them to a List:

```
List<Caption> CaptionList = new List<Caption>();
var obj = new Caption
{
  line = "Some text"
  timestamp = "00:10"
};
CaptionList.Add(obj);
```

I then use Json.NET to serialize the list to Json, like this:

```
public string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CaptionList);
```

Now I want to use this as a JavaScript array, so I tried this:

```
var arr = '<%=json%>';
```

I don't have much JavaScript knowledge, but it seems like `arr` is now a string and not an array because `json` is in fact a C# string. I tried accessing the objects by using `arr[i].line` etc, but that doesn't work.

How do I make the `json`an actually array in JavaScript?

Comment: Just remove single quotes (`'`) around JSON output: `var arr = <%=json%>;`

Comment: Doing that gives me a syntax error though?

Comment: First parse the json to make an object by using  `var JObject = JSON.parse(arr);`

Comment: @Boxiom Most likely that's mean your `json` is invalid

Comment: This should help you : http://www.sitepoint.com/convert-json-string-array/

Comment: Are you using MVC or Asp.Net Web Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JSON.parse` method to parse the JSON string into an array:

```
var arr = JSON.parse('<%=json%>');
```

However, as JSON is a subset of JavaScript syntax, you can actually use the JSON as a JavaScript array literal:

```
var arr = <%=json%>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take it as demo

Your variable `arr` will be rendered like this. This will be string. so to convert a string into JSON Object you need to parse that string. by using `JSON.parse(arr)`

```
var arr = '[ { "line":"Some text", "timestamp":"00:10" }, { "line":"Some text", "timestamp":"00:10" } ]';

var JObject= JSON.parse(arr);

Now you can access JObject[0].line
```

This will give you

> "Some text"

You can take a look [Here at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: What if the JSON string has a quote in one of the values?

Answer (score 2):

We use MVC and in our views (which pass up models) we use a simple line whenever we want to convert the model into a javascript object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            MyObject.Initialize(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
        });
</script>
```

The key to all of that being:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

"Model" is what MVC passes up but you could very easily do something like this: (Razor syntax)

```
@{
   List<Caption> CaptionList = new List<Caption>();
   var obj = new Caption
   {
     line = "Some text"
     timestamp = "00:10"
   };
   CaptionList.Add(obj);
}
```

then...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            MyObject.Initialize(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(CaptionList)));
        });
</script>
```

I haven't tested this but it should work, or some variation of it, you may need to put "CaptionList" as a property in some parent object and pass that into Json.Encode.

You could do this instead, as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(CaptionList)));
        });
</script>
```

Note that jQuery isn't necessary here, it was just a way to wrap it up in the ready function.